# How to make a dictionary application using Oxford Dictionary api?

Tags: java, android, json, api

This is the code which I got from the documentations, I get that, I receive the result in JSON format. But I only need the meaning of the word. So can anyone tell me how do I extract only the meaning of the searched word, rather getting the whole JSON file. I am new to android development, Please help me.

```
package com.example.hsekar.dictionarytestbeta;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new CallbackTask().execute(dictionaryEntries());
}

private String dictionaryEntries() {
    final String language = "en";
    final String word = "Ace";
    final String word_id = word.toLowerCase(); //word id is case sensitive and lowercase is required
    return "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/" + language + "/" + word_id;
}


//in android calling network requests on the main thread forbidden by default
//create class to do async job
private class CallbackTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //TODO: replace with your own app id and app key
        final String app_id = "10742428";
        final String app_key = "ada344f3a7a7c7de0315fb78c5c9d6f9";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("app_id",app_id);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("app_key",app_key);

            // read the output from the server
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }

            return stringBuilder.toString();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Log.d("This will be my result",result);
    }
  }
 }
```

The following is my output. I am just printing it in the Logcat but once I get the concept , I will  start working on the project.

```
This will be my result: {
                          "metadata": {
                              "provider": "Oxford University Press"
                          },
                          "results": [
                              {
                                  "id": "ace",
                                  "language": "en",
                                  "lexicalEntries": [
                                      {
                                          "entries": [
                                              {
                                                  "etymologies": [
                                                      "Middle English (denoting the ‘one’ on dice): via Old French from Latin as ‘unity, a unit’"
                                                  ],
                                                  "grammaticalFeatures": [
                                                      {
                                                          "text": "Singular",
                                                          "type": "Number"
                                                      }
                                                  ],
                                                  "homographNumber": "000",
                                                  "senses": [
                                                      {
                                                          "definitions": [
                                                              "a playing card with a single spot on it, ranked as the highest card in its suit in most card games"
                                                          ],
                                                          "domains": [
                                                              "Cards"
                                                          ],
                                                          "examples": [
                                                              {
                                                                  "registers": [
                                                                      "figurative"
                                                                  ],
                                                                  "text": "life had started dealing him aces again"
                                                              },
                                                              {
                                                                  "text": "the ace of diamonds"
                                                              }
                                                          ],
                                                          "id": "m_en_gbus0005680.006"
                                                      },
                                                      {
                                                          "definitions": [
                                                              "a person who excels at a particular sport or other activity"
                                                          ],
                                                          "domains": [
                                                              "Sport"
                                                          ],
                                                          "examples": [
                                                              {
                                                                  "text": "a motorcycle ace"
                                                              }
                                                          ],
                                                          "id": "m_en_gbus0005680.010",
                                                          "registers": [
                                                              "informal"
                                                          ],
                                                          "subsenses": [
                                                              {
                                                                  "definitions": [
                                                                      "a pilot who has shot down many enemy aircraft"
                                                                  ],
                                                                  "domains": [
                                                                      "Air Force"
                                                                  ],
                                                                  "examples": [
                                                                      {
                                                                          "text": "a Battle of Britain ace"
                                                                      }
                                                                  ],
                                                                  "id": "m_en_gbus0005680.011"
                                                              }
                                                          ]
                                                      },
                                                      {
                                                          "definitions": [
                                                              "(in tennis and similar games) a service that an opponent is unable to return and thus wins a point"
                                                          ],
                                                          "domains": [
                                                              "Tennis"
```

So my question is how do I extract only the 'meaning' part from this output?

Comment: start using retrofit, UrlConnections are dead and gone.

Comment: Have you searched first on how to parse JSON in Java/Android? There are plenty of questions and tutorials to show you how to parse JSON. Some helpful keywords to search for are `java json parsing` and `android json parsing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Json result that you have mentioned is incomplete.the objects in the result are not closed.By the way this is how you get the results from json string.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    try {
       JSONObject js = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray results = js.getJSONArray("results");
        for(int i = 0;i<results.length();i++){
            JSONObject lentries = results.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray la = lentries.getJSONArray("lexicalEntries");
            for(int j=0;j<la.length();j++){
                JSONObject entries = la.getJSONObject(j);
                JSONArray e = entries.getJSONArray("entries");
                for(int i1=0;i1<e.length();i1++){
                    JSONObject senses = la.getJSONObject(i1);
                    JSONArray s = entries.getJSONArray("senses");
                    JSONObject d = s.getJSONObject(0);
                    JSONArray de = d.getJSONArray("definitions");
                    def = de.getString(0);
                }
            }
        }
        Log.e("def",def);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Log.d("This will be my result",result);


        String def = "";
        try {
            JSONObject js = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray results = js.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject lentries = results.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray la = lentries.getJSONArray("lexicalEntries");
                for (int j = 0; j < la.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject entries = la.getJSONObject(j);
                    JSONArray e = entries.getJSONArray("entries");
                    for (int k= 0; k < e.length(); k++) {
                        JSONObject senses = e.getJSONObject(k);
                        JSONArray s = senses.getJSONArray("senses");
                        JSONObject d = s.getJSONObject(0);
                        JSONArray de = d.getJSONArray("definitions");
                        def = de.getString(0);
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.e("def", def);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Log.d("This will be my result",result);
    }
```

Comment: I know this is old but ... it'd be nice if people who felt the need to vote down would actually say why. At least the person who posted took the time to write something, yes? What purpose does it serve to vote down and say nothing? That's not constructive in the slightest.